# Convert a databound combobox's data to ProperCase in VB 2010

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

In VB 2010 I'm trying to show the DisplayMember in ProperCase without modifying my existing MySQL tables.

A snippet of my code looks like this:

```
 Dim sql0 As String = "SELECT business, customer_id FROM customers WHERE cab = '1'"
 Dim data0 As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql0, main.conn)
 Dim ds0 As New DataSet
 ds0.Clear()
 data0.Fill(ds0, "customers")
 cmb_company.DataSource = ds0
 cmb_company.DisplayMember = "customers.business"
 cmb_company.ValueMember = "customers.customer_id"
```

Ive tried something like this:

```
 cmb_company.DisplayMember = StrConv("customers.business_name", VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

but this only changes the case of the part in quotes, and not the actual returned values. I also tried querying from MySQL like this:

```
 "SELECT UPPER(business), customer_id FROM customers WHERE cab = '1'"
```

but this fails to return the "business" field..

I'd love it if my combobox had proper case without changing everything.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Please provide a couple examples of what the input looks like and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second one, but use an alias like this:

```
"SELECT UPPER(business) AS Business, customer_id FROM customers WHERE cab = '1'"
```

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses. For example:
>
> SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name   FROM mytable
>   ORDER BY full_name;

Comment: This is a great solution for solving the *UPPER* part from MySQL, but how about ProperCase? I realize I could substring and lower case the word and then cap the first letter, but adding that much extra work on the server end doesn't make sense.

Isn't there any clean way to do this from VB?

Comment: Thanks for your help @marcus-adams! I'd vote up your suggestion, but I don't have enough reputation O.o

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit silly to use a while loop to achieve this especially after filling the table with an adapter. I suppose I could have just skipped the .fill and added the items manually through the loop, all while ProperCasing them. Anyway, here is my code:

```
        Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT * FROM table"
        Dim data1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql1, main.conn)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        ds1.Clear()
        data1.Fill(ds1, "table")
        cmb_buyout.DataSource = ds1

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            Dim name As String = StrConv(ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) = name
            i += 1
        End While

        cmb_buyout.DisplayMember = "table.buyoutType"
        cmb_buyout.ValueMember = "table.id"
```

To anyone trying to accomplish this, it is probably simpler to just change the case on the entries in the DB. I might just end up doing this!